# Simplifying $0.300 (1 \pm 0.0633)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

This problem had to do with finding area with uncertainty, I got this far but I'm not sure how to go on. 
The answer to the next step is $(0.300 \pm 0.0190)$. How do they get this? What do we do with the 1? 
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I think the title is one step and the next step of the calcul is the part in the question and he can't see the intermediar steps between.

Comment: $0.300(1 \pm 0.0633)=0.300 \times 1 \pm 0.300 \times 0.0633=0.300 \pm 0.0190 $, $ a(b\pm c)=a\times b \pm a \times c$

Comment: Basic rules of posting a question here (or indeed for practically _any_ kind of technical writing): the text should make sense even if you never see the title. In this question, it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

recall the distributive property?
$$a(b+c) = ab + ac$$
or in your case
$$0.300(1±0.0633) = (0.300)(1)\pm (0.300)(0.0633)$$
$$\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

$0.300 * (1$ $^+_- 0.0633)$
$(0.300*1) + (0.300*$ $^+_- 0.0633)$
$0.300 $ $^+_- (0.300*0.0633)$
$0.300 $ $^+_- 0.0190$